# Convert an iterable map object to array object in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to load some json file in a DropdownList from `react-widgets`. When I load the json file the data type looks like this:

```
Map {size: 1, _root: ArrayMapNode, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}
__altered
:
false
__hash
:
undefined
__ownerID
:
undefined
_root
:
ArrayMapNode
size
:
1
__proto__
:
KeyedIterable
```

While the Dropdown component (from `react-widgets`) needs an array! So It makes this error:

```
Failed propType: Invalid prop `data` of type `object` supplied to `DropdownList`, 
expected `array`. Check the render method of `Uncontrolled(DropdownList)`.
```

I can't load the json file directly and I have to use ajax to load it (or technically I can but it's a huge file and each time the user click on the dropdown list it takes couple of seconds to load the data from file). How can I convert this to an array?

P.S. The json file looks like this:

```
{ 
"items":[ 

    { 
    "id": "aaa", 
    "name": "english" 
    }, 
    { 
    "id": "aab", 
    "name": "Swedish" 
    }, 
  ] 
}
```

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I don't know about Immutable.js Maps, I'm quite new in React and JS. I guess it's ES6 maps! :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something along the lines of:

```
var dropdownList = jsonObject.items.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <option key={i} val={item.id}>{item.name}</option>
  );
})
```

The [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function simply goes over a list and produces a new list of the same size but with changes based on the modifier/callback function.

Update based on comment:

Based on the docs for [`DropdownList`](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/docs/#/dropdownlist?_k=e1n5id), you have two options for passing data to the list: a flat array of item names, or a list of objects with specific keys for the item name and value.

Option 1: flat list of item names

```
var itemNames = jsonObject.items.map((item) => item.name );
```

Option 2 : list of objects

```
var items = jsonObject.items.map((item) => {
  return {
    textField: item.name,
    valueField: item.id
  }
});
```

The benefit to using the second option would be when someone selects one of the items, the `event` that is created with point to the `val` attribute of the HTML `<option>`. This is useful for you especially since your ids and names are not the same. An example:

Option 1 (from above):

```
<DropwdownList 
  data={itemNames}
  onSelect: (event) => {
    // Will give the `val` attribute set by DropdownList
    // This might be the item name, or it might be something unique to DrowdownList
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
/>
```

Option 2 (from above):

```
<DropwdownList 
  data={items}
  onSelect: (event) => {
    // Will give the `valueField` attribute you set, which for you is the item's `id` field
    // This might be the item name, or it might be something unique to DrowdownList
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
/>
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I'm using DropdownList from `react-widgets` and it's like:  `<DropdownList 
                    data={jsonArray} 
                    caseSensitive={false} 
                    minLength={3}
                    filter='contains' />`. The `jsonAarray` is the array from json file. According to your answer I tried to convert it but I don't really understand how to do it

Comment: @Sarah I've updated my answer to fir the specific data format for `DropdownList` and explain the options you have available.